# Reading JSON file list returns null (can not read file)

Tags: java, android, json, readfile

I'm trying to read a file that contains a json object but it returns null.
here is my json file

```
[   
{"VersionNumber": 200,
"TitleFA": "TitleFA2",
"DescriptionFA": "DescriptionFA2",
"TitleEN": "TitleEN2",
"DescriptionEN": "DescriptionEN2",
"Priority": 1  },

{"VersionNumber": 100,
"TitleFA": "TitleFA1",
"DescriptionFA": "DescriptionFA1",
"TitleEN": "TitleEN1",
"DescriptionEN": "DescriptionEN1",
"Image": "Image1",
"Priority": 1  } 
]
```

Here is the Class that I'm trying to map it to

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class OnBoardingItemsModel {
 public int VersionNumber;
 public String TitleFA;
 public String DescriptionFA;
 public String TitleEN;
 public String DescriptionEN;
 public String Image;
 public int Priority; }
```

Here is the code I'm using it my fragment to read the file. Also my json file is in the same directory as my fragment class

```
    private List<OnBoardingItemsModel> mOnBoardingItems;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

    try {
        mOnBoardingItems = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(new File("OnBoardingItems.json"), OnBoardingItemsModel[].class));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I tried different ways but `mOnBoardingItems` is always null in the end. I also tries this code and it didn't work: [Java Android – Read JSON file from assets using Gson](https://www.bezkoder.com/java-android-read-json-file-assets-gson/#:%7E:text=put%20assets%20folder%20%26%20JSON%20file,JSON%20string%20to%20Java%20object)

Edit: I tried this and it returned false. I don't know why it's unable to read the file

```
    File file = new File("OnBoardingItems.json");

    Log.v("canreadfile", String.valueOf(file.canRead()));
    Log.v("isfileee", String.valueOf(file.isFile()));
```

I have no idea what else I should check I would appreciate it if someone could help

Comment: You packed all code in one statement. Not a good idea especially when things go different a thought. Split it all up. Do step by step then you will discover where things go wrong.

Comment: `File file = new File("OnBoardingItems.json");`  You should supply a full path to begin with as a file can be every where. You could also first have used file.exists() before trying to read from it. But yes... you are not doing it step by step..

Comment: @blackapps Right I tried to make new file with the absolute path of the file and then tested file.exists() and it returns false. Any Idea why that could be?

Comment: It means that the file does not exist on that path. In that directory. Pretty strange you did not post actual code. How can we help you if you keep it so vague?

Comment: `Also my json file is in the same directory as my fragment class` ???? Abacadabra. Which directory? Come to the point if you need help.

Comment: @blackapps Lol got it thanks. I didn't speculate that it SHOULD be in the assets directory It's fixed now